# Vuetify - how to properly validate group of checkboxes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Is it possible to validate in Vuetify group of checkboxes in the same manner as group of radios? I tried to validate them 'as whole' but each checkbox is validated separately. How to enforce checking at least one of the checkbox fields?

```html
    <template>
    <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form">
    <div v-for="(x, i) in items">
       <v-checkbox
              :true-value="1"
              :false-value="0"
              :rules="[v => !!v || 'You must agree to continue!']"
              v-model="x"
            />
    </div>
    </v-form>
    <template>
```

I would like to have just one mandatory checkbox. Not all of them. Any checkbox from the group of them.

Comment: Show some code. It is very hard to understand what you mean right now.

Comment: I've just added some explanation. My problem is: how to make mandatory to check just one field from the group? I don't want to code each field separately. :/

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```html
<template>
   <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form">
     <div v-for="(x, i) in items">
       <v-checkbox
         :true-value="1"
         :false-value="0"
         :rules="[v => v.length > 0 || 'You must agree to continue!']"
         v-model="x"
        />
      </div>
   </v-form>
<template>
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is too late for answare this thread but it may help someone who want to validate the checkbox in array

---

how work?
this concept is simple,must select atleast one checkbox in array

---

here index==0 ,i want to show error on first element  so i applied :rules 
and then i want to check atleast one element selected so i decided to write condition in given following method by alllow_validate:false. then validation performed in computed.

```
  <div  v-for="(checkbox , index) in yourarray" :key="index">
      <v-checkbox v-if="index==0" @change="Checkboxlist()" :rules="checkbox_rules" label="iam first checkbox" :value="checkbox.cv"></v-checkbox>
     <v-checkbox v-else  @change="Checkboxlist()" label="checkboxfinite" :value="checkbox.checkbox_value"></v-checkbox>

    </div>
```

2.declare data

```
data(){
     yourarray:[{cv:'checkbox1'},{cv:'checkbox2'},{cv:'checkbox3'}],
    alllow_validate:false,
}
```

3.method

```
  methods: {
  Checkboxlist(){

 this.$nextTick(() => {

    var checked=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

var store="";
var firstelement=false;

    for(var i=0;i<checked.length;i++){

     if(checked[i].checked==true)
     {
 this.alllow_validate=true;
if(!firstelement){
   firstelement=true;

   store=checked[i].value;

 }else{
store+=','+checked[i].value;

 this.alllow_validate=false;
 }
         }
    }

//selected checkbox value 
 alert(store);    
    })
}   
  },
```

3.computed

```
computed:{

checkbox_rules(){

const rules=[];

if(this.alllow_validate){

// alert("rule");
 const rule=
           v => (!!v) || "Field is required";
            rules.push(rule)



}
return rules;


}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this?

Pen here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzoVQZ

```
<v-form v-model="valid" ref="form">
  <p>{{ selected }}</p>
  <v-checkbox label="John" 
              v-model="selected"    
              value="John"
              ></v-checkbox>
  <v-checkbox label="Jacob" 
              v-model="selected" 
              value="Jacob"
              ></v-checkbox>
  <v-btn @click="submit">
    SUBMIT
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
<v-snackbar
  :timeout="5000"
  color="red"
  v-model="snackbar"
  >
  Please select at least one checkbox.
  <v-btn dark flat @click.native="snackbar = false">Close</v-btn>
</v-snackbar>



data: () => ({
    //
    snackbar:false,
    selected:['John'],
  }),
   methods: {
      submit () {

        if (this.selected.length > 0){
          this.snackbar = true;
        }

      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Chase. It was validated in Vue way, but not in Vuetify way. Vuetify uses an array of functions to validate form. Like here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#example-validation-with-submit-and-clear  I was wondering if it is possible to validate number of required checboxes in this manner to achieve red borders and shake effect when fields are with errors,